# React Boostrap Select, First Select Option ins not triggered by onChange event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, jsx, react-bootstrap

I'm using React Boostrap Select component :

```
  <Form.Group className="mb-1">
    <Form.Label
      htmlFor="type"
      className="iig-form-label d-inline-block text-truncate"
    >
      Type de projet &nbsp;
      {loadingTypes && <Spinner animation="grow" size="sm" />}
    </Form.Label>
    <Form.Select
      required
      aria-label="Default select example"
      id="type"
      name="type"
      onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
      isInvalid={false}
    >
      // THIS IS THE DEFAULT OPTION THAT IS NOT TRIGGERED    <-------------------
      <option
        value={currentType ? currentType["@id"] : ""}
        data-category={
          currentType ? currentType?.category?.label : ""
        }
      >
        {currentType
          ? currentType.label
          : `Choisir parmi la
        liste des types de projets`}
      </option>
      {filteredTypes.map((filteredTypes, key) => {
        return (
          <option
            value={`/api/types/${filteredTypes.id}`}
            data-category={filteredTypes.category.label}
            key={key}
          >
            {filteredTypes.label}
          </option>
        );
      })}
```

I added a default option to show.

When I click on the default option the `onChange` event is not triggered.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example. Your code snippet misses a lot - handleChange, Spinner, currentType, filteredTypes etc. Either add them to your code or leave them out and add some example data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't follow your example, so I created a minimal example to show you how it works:

- Create state to store the value and **give the id/value of the selected option you want to see initially as default value**
- Write onChange handler
- Pass state value and onChange handler **to Form.Select**
- In Form.Select iterate over you select options list

.

```
const selectOptions = [
  { value: "js", label: "Javascript" },
  { value: "ja", label: "Java" },
  { value: "py", label: "Python" },
  { value: "go", label: "Go" },
  { value: "cs", label: "C#" }
];

export default function App() {
  const [value, selectValue] = useState("js");
  const handleChange = (event) => selectValue(event.target.value);
  return (
    <Form.Group className="mb-1">
      <Form.Select value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
        {selectOptions.map((option) => {
          return <option value={option.value}>{option.label}</option>;
        })}
      </Form.Select>
    </Form.Group>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-gwen-yfmw1m

Comment: thank you for your help, yes i have to set a default value to the state